# phonegap set the root directory for asset files

Tags: cordova

I have seen few questions but I can't find they were old and without any solutions.

So I'n my asset folder I have the following tree:

```
 - ressources
  - img
     - logo.png
  - css
     - style.css
 - process1
  - page1.html
 - index.html
```

My "index.html" when I include img/logo.png or css/style.css everything works fine.

But to have the same result in "page1.html" I must use ../img/logo.png and it's quite annoying since I have a lot of pages.

I have found two ugly solutions:

- Copy the "ressources" folder in each subfolder
- Create a script that will change all the url to the root directory for each os (file:///android_asset/www/ for android)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe a solution is to use the [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) witch allow you to set a default base to all yours relatives links.
So for android it will be:

```
<base href="file:///android_asset/www/" target="_blank">
```

And all yours link will be:

```
<img src="img/logo.png">
```

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what I was looking for! One line to change for each os

Comment: What are the paths for the other two?

Comment: I've been successful in all platforms by using <base href="./">, or at least with iOS and Android